# VS 2015 Error unable to start debugging on the web server. remote server returned an error:(403) forbidden

Tags: asp.net

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLRiB.png)

I copied the website files from another laptop, it works well on that laptop.
I tried resetting the internet services. But still same error is being displayed.i clicked the help button but it did not provide any solution for the applications that are copied or moved
website opens if i type https in the address bar.
i guess there is some configuration settings problem.
i'd appreciate ideas.

Answer (score -1):

I come across the same issue. I have done the following change in the web.config file, add `"debug=true"` as follows:

```
<compilation targetFramework="4.0" debug="true"/>
```

Now it is working fine for me.